# Inserting html file from another component without creating new DOM container in Ionic 4

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to create a reusable Floating Action Button component, but it doesn't fixed it position on the screen when I call its selector in another file.

This is a website made with Angular and Ionic 4, I tried inspecting on google chrome, and within the scope of my understanding this is the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqjGn.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/14JBl.jpg

The highlighted button is the problematic one, the bottom right button is working perfectly. If you take a closer look on the element inspect, it shows that the button is within "app-floating-button" container which is the selector for my floating button component.

```
<!--main.page.html-->
<ion-content>
  <!--working sticky button-->
  <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
    <ion-fab-button>
      <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
    </ion-fab-button>
  </ion-fab>
  <!--Text area-->
  <ion-text>
    text here
  </ion-text>
  <!--imported component-->
  <app-floating-button></app-floating-button>
</ion-content>
```

```
<!--floating-button.component.html-->
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="end" slot="fixed">
  <ion-fab-button>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
  </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>
```

```
//floating-button.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-floating-button',
  templateUrl: './floating-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./floating-button.component.scss'],
})
export class FloatingButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() position: String;
  @Input() link: String;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

I expect the imported component to work just like the "working sticky button", I ran out of ideas to put the content of floating-button.component.html on main.html without wrapping it inside "app-floating-button" container

p.s. not enough reputation to post images sorry :(